# Problems deferencing the Hash value from Net::Twitter

Tags: perl, twitter, hash

Im using the Net::Twitter module from CPAN, but I'm having a small issue with it.

The following subroutine searches for a term on Twitter but I cant seem to get anything
but a HASH value (ie. %HASH(0x9096dc0) )

How do I go about getting just the contents of the tweet?

```
sub twit_search
{
 my $term = shift @_;

 my $page = 1;
 my @results;


 while (scalar @results < $opts{maxresults})
 {
  my $rset = $handle->search({query=>$term, page => $page, rpp => $opts{rpp} });

  print "Searching for $term (page $page)\n" if $opts{verbose};

  if (ref $rset eq 'HASH' && exists $rset->{results})
  {
   last unless @{$rset->{results}};

   push @results, @{$rset->{results}};

   printf "Now we have %d entries\n", scalar @results if $opts{verbose};
  }

  $page++;
 }

 foreach my $tweet (@results)
 {
  print $tweet; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting back is actually a hash reference, which can be used to get at the hash containing the actual data.  You can `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($tweet);` to see the full structure and contents of the tweet.

It's been a year or so since I last wrote Twitter-related code, but I believe the actual text of the tweet should be in the "text" key, so, to print that, use

```
print $tweet->{text};
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Good memory. Data Dumper is definitely one to remember.